# Limit hover area of CSS shapes to :after

Tags: html, css, hover, css-shapes

I am trying to make a sort of Venn-Diagram that is going to be used for navigation later.

I have three intersecting ellipsoids created with CSS shapes. Each ellipsoid, as well as their two intersections, will be distinct links later on. Also, when you hover over them they should pop out as per `transform: scale(1.3)`.

My issue is that I'm using ellipsoids which are partially transparent with `:after` to create the intersections, which creates a problem when hovering over them because the `:hover` condition gets triggered when hovering anywhere on the partially transparent ellipsoid and not just the `:after part`. This means that the nonintersecting areas are not hoverable because they are obstructed by the other invisible ellipsoid.

I think the example will make this clearer.

Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.venn-container{position: relative; left: 0;}
.cat_one{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.cat_two{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 240px;
  opacity: 0.5;

}
.cat_three{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 480px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.int1{
  background: transparent;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.int1:after{
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 240px;
}
.int1:hover{
  transform: scale(1.3);
  left: -35px;
}
.int2{
  background: transparent;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  left: 80px;
}
.int2:after{
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 200px / 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  left: -240px;
}
.int2:hover{
  transform: scale(1.3);
  left: 115px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="venn-container">
<div class="cat_one"></div>
<div class="cat_two"></div>
<div class="cat_three"></div>
<div class="int1"></div>
<div class="int2"></div>
</div>
```

And here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3Lvmuqg/2/

I would like the `:hover` to only get triggered in the intersections, and later make `cat_one` and `cat_two` hoverable outside the intersections.

I don't know if there is a way I'm doing this is the best and I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Try like this `int1:hover::after` and give `transition` ti the int1

Comment: What do you mean by transition to int1?

Comment: transition property.

Comment: You mean transition: 1s; ?

Comment: yes `transition: all 2s linear;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for getting back to me @ge0rg I spent about an hour fiddling with <kbd>CSS</kbd> and <kbd>HTML</kbd> and came up with this code using just `div`s with `background colors`, `hover events` and `border radius`'s (along with a few `z-index` and `positioning techniques`).
Hope you enjoy your reworked venn diagram...
You may have to mess around with the size, and definetly will have to mess with the positioning (however they're all inside a div and so it makes it so that you can just position the div and the rest will happen magically) I added a background color to the div just to show that nothing was transparent, and I also added a always on top function for viewing a section, and I hope you enjoy!

```css
.Venn {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue, lightblue);
}
.d1:hover, .d2:hover, .d3:hover {
 color: #565656;
 animation: top 2s steps(2, end) forwards;
 -webkit-animation: top 2s steps(2, end) forwards;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
}

.d1, .d2, .d3 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.d1 center, .d3 center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.d1 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}

.d3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 81px;
}

.d1:hover, .d3:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.d2 {
  border-radius: 100% 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 87.5px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 55.35px;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.d2b {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.d2b center {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

.d2:hover {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.Venn {
  height: 100px;
}

-webkit @keyframes top {
  99% {
    z-index: previous;
    background-image: none;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 7;
  }
}

@keyframes top {
  99% {
    z-index: previous;
    background-image: none;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Venn" style="position: relative; left: 50px; width: 300px; height: 100px;">

  <div class="d1" style=" background-color: grey;">
    <center> 1 </center>
  </div>

  <div class="d2" style=" background-color: #AAAAAA;">
    <div class="d2b" style="max-width: inherit;">
      <center> 2 </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d3" style=" background-color: lightgrey;">
    <center> 3 </center>
  </div>

</div>
```

For those of you who would prefer a JSfiddle/ CodePen here you go [a Codepen](https://codepen.io/Techtiger255YT/pen/BqxQpd).

Comment: You may remove the background color and mess with anything you want ( I recommend using the codepen ) so you can figure how exactly you need it.

Comment: I'm sure your smart enough to figure out how to make a third, just add it to all the multi ones, make a new intersection and position it how you like. Vuala!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. And I already thought that I have to move to svgs to make it work.

Comment: Glad I could help, but just for clarification, this isn't SVG's... SVG's would look something like [this code](https://codepen.io/VisualAngle/pen/mzKKZW) or [this code](https://codepen.io/Techtiger255YT/pen/OBENEj) this `<img src="` **`kiwi.svg`** `" >` would work too... Svgs are **S**calable **V**ector **G**raphics and are an image type that will stay the same quality no matter the render size. These are mainly used for icons. They could, however, work in this situation; Although the div's are easier and probably more practical. Just wanted to clarify...